# Lazy Resource Loading class in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, lazy

Recently I was studying about the benefits and uses of `std::optional` in C++17 ([Bartek's Blog](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/05/using-optional.html)) and there I saw a line that said "`std::optional` can be used for Lazy Loading of Resources" . Upon digging a little bit, I saw that C++ does not have native support for Lazy evaluation. So I just gave it a try and wrote the following code for lazy evaluation in C++.

**Lazy.ixx** - Visual Studio(Experimental :Modules)

To compile this (VS2019):

```
cl /experimental:module /EHsc /TP /MD /std:c++latest Lazy.ixx /module:interface /module:output Lazy.pcm /Fo: Lazy.obj /c
```

```
#include<optional>
#include<functional>
export module Lazy;

export namespace gstd
{
template<typename T>
class Lazy
{
   std::optional<T> m_resource;
   std::function<T()>m_ctor_func;
public:
   Lazy(std::function<T()>ctor_func)
   {
       m_ctor_func=ctor_func; 
   }
   std::optional<T> operator ->()
   {
     //If resource is not initialized(i.e Ctor not invoked/ first time use)
    if(!m_resource)
    {
        m_resource=m_ctor_func();
    }
     return m_resource;
   }
};
}
```

Now sorry for using modules! (I just love them). To use this class it's pretty simple:

```
//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
import Lazy;

// A simple class called Resource
class Resource
{
  public:
  Resource()
  {
    std::cout<<"Welcome to new C++\n";
  }
  Resource(int a, int b)
  {
    std::cout<<"This also works : "<<a<<" "<<b<<"\n";
  }
  void func()
  {
    std::cout<<"Resource::func()\n";
  }

};

int main()
{
   gstd::Lazy<Resource>resx([](){ return Resource(4,5); });
   std::cout<<"Before construction\n";

   //Some code before using the resource

   resx->func();
   std::cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

To compile this:

```
cl /experimental:module /module:reference Lazy.pcm /std:c++latest /TP /MD /EHsc /c /Fo: main.obj main.cpp
```

Get the executable by linking those two files:

```
cl main.obj Lazy.obj
```

I am pretty much new to programming so please bear me with the silly mistakes. One problem that can be seen at the first glance is this class (Lazy) is not thread-safe. Implementing that would be easy with mutexes. But, other than that, how can I improve my code?

Comment: Why are you storing/returning `std::optional` if you always return it with the value set?

Comment: I am returning std::optional<T> because of the problem with operator-> According to docs "It has additional, atypical constraints: It must return an object (or reference to an object) that also has a pointer dereference operator, or it must return a pointer that can be used to select what the pointer dereference operator arrow is pointing at." **  Now this behavior could be emulated by converting that to pointer and returning it but it will introduce a whole new set of problems among which the deadliest one is that people may get a false sense of assumption that the returned obj  is a pointer

Comment: Which may make people do weird stuff like deleting that pointer or trying to assign something else.  On the other hand I feel that returning a std::optional<T> would keep the users aware about what type of object they are dealing with

Comment: Also using std::optional sometimes  does have a memory penalty due to alignment issues

Comment: Just return a `T*`, people can't do strange things with it without explicitly calling `operator->`.  That's what the standard facilities do (and is the intended method).

Answer (score 1):

#### Preface

I am using Apple Clang 10 and the following commands to build.

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -fmodules-ts --precompile Lazy.cppm -o Lazy.pcm
clang++ -std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -c Lazy.pcm -o Lazy.o
clang++ -std=c++17 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. Lazy.o main.cpp
```

I'm using C++ 17 since that's the tag on the question, although I believe MSVC `/std:c++latest` corresponds to the parts of C++ 20 that are already implemented on MSVC.

I had one compilation error when I first tried this:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:
Lazy.cppm:10:21: error: definition of 'optional' must be imported from module 'Lazy.<global>'
      before it is required
   std::optional<T> m_resource;
                    ^
main.cpp:26:24: note: in instantiation of template class 'gstd::Lazy<Resource>' requested here
   gstd::Lazy<Resource>resx([](){ return Resource(4,5); });
```

I solved it by adding `#include <optional>` in main.cpp, but maybe there's a better way.  Please let me know if there is a better solution.  I have only toyed around with modules so I'm far from an expert.

#### Fix your indentation

Minor nitpick: use consistent indentation.
You have 4 spaces for most of it (which is fine) but 1 space in a few spots.
And 0 spaces in a few spots too.  There are tools that can do this for you automatically (although it's pretty
easy to just do it by hand).

#### Consider using `operator T`

C++ can implicitly convert your object into a T:

```
template <typename T>
struct Lazy {
    operator const T&() {
        ...
    }
};

int main() {
    Lazy<int> n(...);
    return n;
}
```

#### Consider making access `const`

When you access an object, you don't expect to modify it.  In other words, you should be able to write:

```
Lazy<int> const n(...);
int x = n + 2;
```

This implies an object that looks something like

```
template <typename T>
struct Lazy {
    operator const T&() const {
        ...
    }
private:
    std::optional<T> mutable opt;
};
```

#### Think about what kind of functions you want to support

As you've written it now, you have two std::functions: the argument to the ctor and the one in the object.  You should at most have one.  You could use std::move.

```
Lazy(std::function<T()> ctor_func)
    : m_ctor_func(std::move(ctor_func)) // at least do this!
{}
```

At least use a member initializer list instead of initialization by assignment.

It may be preferable to get rid of std::function completely and instead use a template parameter.
This would allow you to get rid of all the copying.
You could even have non-copyable types in the function object.
You could even go overboard and deduce the stored type based on the templated function.  Then you could just write:

```
Lazy const n([nc=NonCopyable()]{ return 1; });
```

No template arguments!  It's up to you to decide whether this is a good idea, but it may be a good exercise if you
are new to templates.

#### Use optional::emplace

... instead of assignment.